# Laravel 5 Eager loading with a function

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have a function in my model (WeeshUser) that returns email if there are no Name or Surname for the user.

```
// RETURN EMAIL OR NAME
public function nameOrEmail() {
    $return = " - ";
    // Check for first name
    if ($this->first_name) {
        $return = $this->first_name;
        // Add lastname if exists
        if ($this->last_name) {
            $return .= " " . $this->last_name;
        }
    } elseif ($this->last_name) {
        // if only lastname exists
        $return = $this->last_name;
    } else {
        //else return email
        $return = $this->email;
    } 
    return $return;
}
```

I would like to call this function when eager loading from a controller ex:

```
$weeshReturn = WeeshShare::with('sender.nameOrEmail')->get();
```

The sender object is a WeeshUser object, and if run this without the .nameOrEmail it runs fine, but if run it like this I get an error

> Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because Eloquent is assuming *nameOrEmail* is a relation to *sender* and expects it to return `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` object, but you return a string from it.

nameOrEmail is a normal method on the *sender* class and it does not to be eager loaded, you already eager load *sender*.

What you can do instead is:

```
$weeshReturn = WeeshShare::with('sender')->get();
$weeshReturn->sender->nameOrEmail();
```

Comment: If you want to simplify things even more you can use a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators).